# JS heatmap canvas download (empty canvas though heat map is displaying)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, heatmap

I want to download the resulting JS heat map I have created using setData of my own points. The heatMap is being displayed but when I download the canvas I get an empty picture.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heatmap Test Code</title>
<script src='http://www.patrick- 
wied.at/static/heatmapjs/assets/js/heatmap.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="heatMap" style="height:740px">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="540" 
style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0"></canvas>
  </div>
    <a id="download" download="triangle.jpeg"><button type="button" 
onClick="download()">Download</button></a>
    <img id="myImage">

</body>
<script> 
  var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
    container: document.getElementById('heatMap')
  });

  var testData = {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        data: [{x: 807, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 770, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 
750, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 750, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 200, y: 583, 
value: 500},{x: 750, y: 583, value: 500}, {x: 597, y: 285, value: 51}, {x: 
217, y: 449, value: 73}, {x: 377, y: 656, value: 58}, {x: 467, y: 509, 
value: 47}, {x: 487, y: 164, value: 46}, {x: 247, y: 194, value: 35}]
  };
  heatmapInstance.setData(testData);

    function download(){
        var download = document.getElementById("download");
        var image = 
document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png")
                .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
          download.setAttribute("href", image);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, well H337 isn't using your canvas. You're providing the container, and it's creating a canvas in that div.

```
var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
  container: document.getElementById('heatMap')
});
```

If you run your page and inspect the heatmap you'll see there's two canvas elements in that div. Remove yours and select the heatmap by class:

http://jsfiddle.net/79abc2sx/5/

Comment: Thank you i just realized that while inspecting the elements and extracted the URI (URL) of the canvas the map created by accessing the div's child and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You're close, set the Href to the image, then trigger download:

```
link.href = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();
link.download = 'image_name.png';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zx23ep0g/15/

Comment: thanks for the correct download approach.I tried it with a normal simple canvas and it works but my problem is that it still downloads an empty pictures,I am guessing my problem is with the heat map drawn in the canvas part which i still couldnt figure .I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

This is my full adjusted (with offwhite remark above added) and working code to draw A JS Heat Map based on a set of points with their respective values and download that map as a PNG if anyone needed the working code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heatmap Test Code</title>
<script src='http://www.patrick- 
wied.at/static/heatmapjs/assets/js/heatmap.min.js'></script>

<script>
function load(){
  renderCanvas();

  // add listener to the download button
  document.getElementById('download').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function() {download(this)},
  false
 );
}

// draw your heatmap here
function renderCanvas(){
 var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
    container: document.getElementById('heatMap')
  });

  var testData = {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        data: [{x: 807, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 770, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 
750, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 750, y: 583, value: 500},{x: 200, y: 583, 
value: 500},{x: 750, y: 583, value: 500}, {x: 597, y: 285, value: 51}, {x: 
217, y: 449, value: 73}, {x: 377, y: 656, value: 58}, {x: 467, y: 509, 
value: 47}, {x: 487, y: 164, value: 46}, {x: 247, y: 194, value: 35}]
  };
  heatmapInstance.setData(testData);
}

function download(link){

  link.href = 
(document.getElementById("heatMap").childNodes[1]).toDataURL();
//    console.log(document.getElementById("heatMap").childNodes[1]);
  link.download = 'image_name.png';
 }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
  <div id="heatMap" style="height:740px" >
  </div>
  <a id="download" href="#">Download as image</a>

</body>
</html>
```